# check duplicated email and remove it from file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have two files, email_liste1.txt ; email_liste2.txt. I would like to remove all email which exist in email_liste2 file from email_liste1 file.

finally I want to have email_liste1 without email address which exist in email_liste2.

> email_liste1  and email_liste2 contain only email address

example :

email_list1 : {name1@email.com ; name2@email.com ; name3@email.com ; name4@email.com ; name5@email.com ;name6@email.com ; etc ...}.

email_list1: { name2@email.com ; name3@email.com ; name4@email.com ; etc ...}

so, there is any way to do that with Linux command ?
thank

Comment: You can use `grep -f file1 file2`. It will compare one file with the other.

Comment: Are you talking about real emails (e.g. in an mbox file), or a list of email *addresses*?

Comment: @ fedorqui: this command allow only to compare tow files but how to remove email address which exist in email_liste2 file from email_liste1 file.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi : no just email list in txt file

Comment: Your file format isn't very conducive to automated management by the traditional line-oriented Unix tools. Change your file format to one email address per line and the problem becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep's "-v" flag to invert the match.

```
$ cat file1
name1@email.com
name2@email.com
name3@email.com
name4@email.com

$ cat file2
name2@email.com
name4@email.com

$ grep -v -f file2 file1
name1@email.com
name3@email.com

$ grep -v -f file2 file1 > new-file

$ cat new-file
name1@email.com
name3@email.com
```